# Client gets the wrong exception message

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-security

I would like to get an exception with the message "Password is not correct".

This is what I have tried:

```java
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<Object> login(@RequestBody CustomUserDetails user) {
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
    if (userDetails == null || !passwordEncoder.matches(user.getPassword(), userDetails.getPassword())) {
        throw new CustomAuthenticationException("Password is not correct");
    }

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String token = jwt.generateToken(user);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(token);
}
```

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationException extends AuthenticationException {
    public CustomAuthenticationException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class AuthControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(PSQLException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handlePSQLException() {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, LocalDateTime.now(), "User already exists");
        return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadCredentialsException() {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, LocalDateTime.now(), "Invalid username or password");
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorResponse);
    }
}
```

If the password is not correct, this is the response that the client receives:

```json
{
    "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "timestamp": "28.02.2023, 11:06:14",
    "message": "Invalid username or password"
}
```

This is the wrong message. What I expect is `throw new CustomAuthenticationException("Password is not correct");`. When I run the debug mode, that line will get executed but it is not returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behavior because the class CustomAuthenticationException extends AuthenticationException. And the exception handler is only defined fot the super class AuthenticationException.

Please add another handler for your custom exception. Similar to this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(CustomAuthenticationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadCredentialsException(Exception exception) {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, LocalDateTime.now(), exception.getMessage());
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it.

```
@ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadCredentialsException(AuthenticationException exception) {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, LocalDateTime.now(), exception.getMessage());
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorResponse);
}
```